# Got 'undefined' when using $scope.$parent but it has data

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to access data in $scope.$parent. I always get undefined while I am trying to access but the log of $scope.$parent has the data.

For instance,

```
app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.parentData = {
        name : 'Beacon',
        address : 'Cheese'
    };
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope){
    console.log($scope.$parent); // There is parentData in log
    console.log($scope.$parent.parentData); // it show 'undefined'
});
```

I don't understand what I did wrong. Very thank you for help.

**edit**
Here is the screen captured of console.log($scope.$parent);
[image]

Comment: Can you show output of `console.log($scope.$parent);`?

Comment: @Manwal I added it in the post edtting.

Comment: did you try using controller 'as' notation instead of using $parent?

Answer (score 0):

I can see the output of your console.log as below

```
console.log($scope.$parent); 
Object { $id: "004", this: Object, $$listeners: Object, $$listenerCount: Object, $parent: Object, $$childTail: Object, $$childHead: Object, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: null, $$prevSibling: null, 1 more… } index.html:16:4


console.log($scope.$parent.parentData); 
 Object { name: "Beacon", address: "Cheese" }
```

Please paste your HTMl where you included the controllers.